# How to show all data from SQLite in BaseAdapter in custom layout?

Tags: android, listview, show

This code shows me some accidental data from the database, but not exactly one by one, sometimes show the same data 10 times, what can be the solution to the problem?

```
    listItem = new ArrayList<>();
    customAdapter customAdapter = new customAdapter();
    userlist = v.findViewById(R.id.lisview); 
    userlist.setDivider(null);
    userlist.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

My custom adapter

```
class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int cursor = databaseHelper.getAllServiceAll().getCount();
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);
        TextView showprice = view.findViewById(R.id.showprice);
        TextView showliters = view.findViewById(R.id.showLiters);
        TextView showdata = view.findViewById(R.id.showdata);
        TextView showvalute = view.findViewById(R.id.showvalute);
        Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getAllServiceAll();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        cursor.moveToNext();
        String formula4S = new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(2)));
            showprice.setText(formula4S); // Price
            showdata.setText(cursor.getString(3) ); // data
            showvalute.setText("" + databaseHelper.getValute ()); // Valute
            showliters.setText(cursor.getString(1) ); // Liters

        return view;
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java:

```
public Cursor getAllServiceAll (){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM servis ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10", null);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: why dont you use `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: Why cant you just pass the list to the adapter from the fragment/activity and return the count as the size of the list.

Comment: showvalute.setText("" + databaseHelper.getValute ()); // Valute

Comment: Also you are using `Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getAllServiceAll(); cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.moveToNext();` code inside `getView()` Method. It might cause issue while user will scroll the list.

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you get the ArrayList of items back in your Activity and pass that to your Adapter.  Here is one example of the code in the Activity:

```
private DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
private ListView mLocationList;
private TextView mEmptyList;
static  ArrayList<LocationAddress> locationList = new ArrayList<LocationAddress>();
private LocationsListAdapter adapter;

....

    thisContext = this;

    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(thisContext);

    mLocationList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_browse);

    mLocationList.setOnItemClickListener(new LocationClickListener());

// at this point locationList is empty      
    adapter = new LocationsListAdapter(thisContext, locationList);
    mLocationList.setAdapter(adapter);

// now, get the locationList by calling a background Async Task 
    new GetLocations().execute(""); 


   private class GetLocations extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;    

    @Override     
    protected void onPreExecute() {   

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(thisContext);         
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait...");         
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);         
        dialog.setCancelable(false);         
        dialog.show();     

        }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String results = "";
            locationList = new ArrayList<LocationAddress>();

            try {

                myDbHelper.openDataBase();

            }catch(SQLException sqle){
                results = "Error Opening Database";

                throw sqle;

            }

            Cursor c = null;

            try{

                c = myDbHelper.getLocations();

                if (c != null) { 
                    if (c.moveToFirst())
                    {

                        do { 

                            LocationAddress location = new LocationAddress();

                            location.setID(c.getInt(0));
                            location.setName(c.getString(1));
                            location.setAddress(c.getString(2));
                            location.setLatitude(c.getDouble(3));
                            location.setLongitude(c.getDouble(4));
                            location.setType(c.getString(5));
                            location.setSortOrder(c.getInt(6));

                            locationList.add(location);

                        } while (c.moveToNext());
                    }
                }

                if (c != null) { 
                    if (!c.isClosed()) {
                        c.close();  
                    }
                }

            } catch (Throwable t){
                if (c != null) { 
                    if (!c.isClosed()) {
                        c.close();  
                    }
                }
            }

            try {

                myDbHelper.close();

            }catch(SQLException sqle){
                results = "SQL Error";
                throw sqle;

            }

            return results;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
        dialog.dismiss(); 

        if (results != null) {
            if (results.length() > 0) {
                alertMessage("Get Locations", results);
            } else {

            // This refreshes the adapter with a full list of items
                adapter = new LocationsListAdapter(thisContext, locationList);
                mLocationList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

    }
} // private Class
```

And the Adapter class looks like this:

```
public class LocationsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<LocationAddress> locationItems;

public LocationsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LocationAddress> locationItems){
    this.context = context;
    this.locationItems = locationItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return locationItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {       
    return locationItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.location_list_item, null);
    }
    LinearLayout topLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location_top_layout);
    TextView txtSectionTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location_section_title);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location_title);
    TextView txtAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location_address);

    String previous_section_title = "";
    String section_title = "";

    if (position > 0) {
        previous_section_title = locationItems.get(position - 1).getType();
    }

    section_title = locationItems.get(position).getType();
    String location_title = locationItems.get(position).getName();
    String location_address = locationItems.get(position).getAddress();

    txtSectionTitle.setText(section_title);

    if (section_title.contentEquals(previous_section_title)) {
        topLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        topLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    txtTitle.setText(location_title);
    txtAddress.setText(location_address);


    return convertView;
}

}
```